# Can air itself be theoretically considered as a (very poor) wireless ESD grounding strap?

Tags: esd, static, static-electricity

There are many kinds of questionable ESD wriststraps available which
claim to provide ESD protection "wirelessly". When asked about how
exactly they work, they cite dubious claims about physics as their
theory of operation. Many experiments have repeatedly shown that they're
ineffective at preventing ESD from the human body for the purpose of
electronics manufacturing. One can find many publications from both
trade journals and personal blogs. In fact, a teardown showed some
"wireless" ESD wriststraps are just regular wriststraps without a wire
installed - even the megaohm resistor was kept as-is, making them a big
joke among engineers.

But thinking from here, it makes me wonder whether the air itself can be
theoretically considered a "wireless ESD grounding strap" - although
a very poor one with negligible effect in most applications and are certainly not a practical device for ESD protection during electronics assembly. It's based on the following ideas:

1. Air is an insulator but its conductivity is non-zero.
2. It's possible to define an electric potential from air to Earth ground.
   Above an idealized Earth ground or seawater, there exists an electric
   potential gradient around 100 V/m (when the field is not distorted
   by a conductive object).
3. When equipotential grounding is impractical, an air ionizer can be
   used as a workaround to increase the conductivity of air, thus reducing the occurrence of ESD by allowing charged objects to discharge to ground. Similarly, increasing the humidity of a room has the same effect.
4. Some applications discharge ESD directly into the air. For example,
   on aircraft, high static potentials can build up on airframes due to
   triboelectricity, so they include sharp static discharge wicks to
   discharge ESD into the air in a controlled manner. (This discharge
   takes place even without a wick, the purpose of a wick is to ensure
   that it originates at a predictable location instead of a random piece
   of metal).

[image: A portion of a static wick on an aircraft.]

Thus, one can imagine the following thought experiment:

Imagine an ESD-safe room. In this room,
its floor and all of the workbenches are covered by ESD mats, and are all bonded to the power
ground, and thus, the Earth ground. Now imagine an object is suddely
magically created, insulated from ground and with an extremely high
potential with respect to the Earth ground. Now the experiment is started.
Initially, an electrostatic discharge to air occurs. If an object has a sharp point, it would
occur at this location, if it does not, it occurs at a random location.
After this discharge, its potential is equalized to the potential of the
air at this height, perhaps 100 V plus a residue value.

### Question

1. *Does it make sense?* - Is the thought experiment correct, at least in a
   rough sense?
2. *Would it work?* - Theoretically, does the same thought experiment work for
   the human body? If so, is it correct to say that air is a ESD grounding strap?  (but with negligible effect in practice, of course).
3. *Would it really happen?* - Is there any theoretical scenario that would
   create a static potential on the object (or human body) so high that it would
   spontaneously discharge into the air, with or even without a sharp point?
   Entirely hypothetical scenarios are acceptable, such as assuming the humans are
   spherical and initially charged in a vacuum.
4. *If it does work, how practical is it?* - If such a scenario indeed theoretically
   exists and the "ESD protection from thin air" theoretically works, how much static
   potential does the object (or human body) need to have before a discharge takes place,
   and how much residue potential is still on the object after the discharge takes place?
   From my experience with spark gaps, I think the voltage involved is around many kilovolts,
   but I'm not sure how a ESD discharge from an object into the surrounding air can be
   analyzed (unlike the case of discharging to ground, which is a simple dielectric
   breakdown problem), pointers to relevant books and papers would be appreciated.

In summary, the question is whether an electrically-charged object can be spontaneously be discharged to air.

Comment: @All - Some comments here have become (at least partial) answers, which is not an allowed use of them. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued *there* (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. *Keep it in chat now, please!* || Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comment: *Comments have been moved to [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151913/discussion-on-question-by--is-it-theoretically-possible-to-make-a-wireless-e) and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.*

Answer (score 9):

> Does it make sense? - Is the thought experiment correct, at least in a rough sense?

Air has about 10^9Ω to 10^13Ω depending on conditions like humidity and composition and the amount of ions in the air, so it's a very bad pathway for current. Yes 'high' points create a better pathway by shortening the distance and by creating a higher electric field gradient for elections to jump off of/onto.

ESD can occur without an ESD event, some gates of mosfets (not usually these days because they have ESD protection built in) can be blown out just by exposing it to an electric field - the gates are nanometers thin and it doesn't take much voltage build up to exceed Vgs and blow them out. The whole point of ESD safety and protection is to make sure nothing in the room is at a high potential vs ground, because it's the electric fields that can also cause problems. In an aerospace ESD bench, you can't even have materials like paper or certain types of plastic because they can develop charge. Another problem is humans, they develop charge and touch a device and then cause damage. ESD safety is also to keep humans at the bench potential.

> Would it work? - Theoretically, does the same thought experiment work for the human body? If so, is it correct to say that air is a ESD
> grounding strap? (but with negligible effect in practice, of course).

No. Air is definitely not an ESD grounding strap. Even with ionizers and humidity control to help make air more conductive, it's not sufficient to replace an ESD strap.

> Would it really happen? - Is there any theoretical scenario that would create a static potential on the object (or human body) so high
> that it would spontaneously discharge into the air, with or even
> without a sharp point? Entirely hypothetical scenarios are acceptable,
> such as assuming the humans are spherical and initially charged in a
> vacuum.

It's really the potential that matters and the breakdown of air, at a certain point the air ionizes itself to the point it becomes a plasma and then it becomes very conductive. Sharp objects help this process, but its really the breakdown of air that makes a spark, not the object.

> If it does work, how practical is it? - If such a scenario indeed theoretically exists and the "ESD protection from thin air"
> theoretically works, how much static potential does the object (or
> human body) need to have before a discharge takes place, and how much
> residue potential is still on the object after the discharge takes
> place? From my experience with spark gaps, I think the voltage
> involved is around many kilovolts, but I'm not sure how a ESD
> discharge from an object into the surrounding air can be analyzed
> (unlike the case of discharging to ground, which is a simple
> dielectric breakdown problem), pointers to relevant books and papers
> would be appreciated.

For the reasons listed in the first question having any electric field potential near a bench or in an ESD protected space the idea of the use of air as a way to mitigate ESD is a non-starter.

Comment: "Air has about 10^9Ω to 10^13Ω" Over what distance?

Comment: It's a rough figure to give readers an idea of what it is, if you want to get in to the nitty gritty you can get currents in the pA range until you turn up the voltage. Of course air gaps narrow that range and increase breakdown. That wont change anything in the answer

Comment: I understand, I was just prompting you to use the proper units.  A mm of air will not have the same resistance as a meter of air.  The numbers you gave should be per meter by the way.  I agree it is weird to talk about air as having a "resistance" anyway, as it hardly behaves like a resistor.

Comment: My definition of a "very poor ESD grounding strap" is strictly theoretical - it doesn't need to be practical, as long as the air can limit an object's potential by discharging it to the surrounding air (but *not* a full dielectric breakdown to ground), it is a grounding strap according in my definition. In this sense, I think my assumption is correct. Now real question is the order of magnitude involved. On second thought, this is equivalent to a "deoptimized" Van Der Graaf generator, with an electrode shape deliberately designed to promote discharges rather than suppressing it.

Comment: It can take hours to drain high voltages through the air (even a small capacitor or object that has electric potentials can take a long time to drain), all the while the voltages are dangerous to electronics. You can promote electrons to go into air, but you can't change the air from being saturated with electrons and if the air is saturated there will be no current. This idea might work on a short distance, but would not work on long distances, because the effect of the point on the electric field would be negligible after a (perhaps) few cm

Answer (score 7):

> Does it make sense? - Is the thought experiment correct, at least in a rough sense?

I'm not clear what part of your question is "the thought experiment". But you are correct that it is possible for highly charged objects to discharge through the air.

> Would it work?

Yes, it is possible to discharge objects through the air (you yourself mentioned the use of ionized air curtains). But no, without the use of ionized air, it won't discharge the object completely and reliably enough to fulfil the function of an ESD strap, which is to prevent damage to the object or to other sensitive devices nearby.

> Would it really happen? - Is there any theoretical scenario that would create a static potential on the object (or human body) so high that it would spontaneously discharge into the air, with or even without a sharp point?

Of course it is possible. We have photographic evidence:

[image]

(source: [Physics Stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203204/tesla-coil-arc-in-air-where-is-it-going))

> If it does work, how practical is it? - If such a scenario indeed theoretically exists and the "ESD protection from thin air" theoretically works,

It is entirely impractical as ESD protection. The discharge itself is likely to cause the damage that we normally use ESD protection to avoid.

Comment: I think It's possible to make such this ESD discharge less destructive, albeit only a little bit less. Aircraft static discharge wicks are connected to an airframe via an insulator with a resistance around 6-200 megaohm. This is similar to the high resistivity of ESD mats, or the megaohm resistor of the wriststrap.

Comment: @比尔盖子, I guess it's up to you how you want to define "practical".

Comment: @比尔盖子 The potential that you need - even given a sharp tip - to provoke a corona discharge, is so high that the object would be prone to ESD damage regardless.

Comment: A radio engineer I used to know once told me, "at 50,000 volts, everything is a conductor, even the air". The difference being some things are better conductors and are also better suited to handle a resulting flow of current without massive damage.